# main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file:

Tags: magento2, email, order-email, magento2.2.4, invalid-template

I created module for email header

Block: INW\EmailOverride\Block\EmailOverride // information about which image show

template: extraheader.phtml // contain a image tag

I put this in custom email template

{{block class="INW\EmailOverride\Block\EmailOverride" name="extraheader_header"  orderId=$myvar1 template="INW_EmailOverride::extraheader.phtml"}}

when I am sending email from 2 places

1. Vendor1_Module1 Observer send email: email sent, working fine no problem extraheader working fine
2. Vendor2_Module2 Controller send email: email sent but extraheader part missing and showing error in log

main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'INW_EmailOverride::extraheader.phtml' in module: 'INW_EmailOverride' block's name: 'emailoverride_0' [] []

Comment: Post your code which is easy way to help

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, Vendor2_Module2 Controller is a admin controller, so extraheader.phtml should be adminhtml/templates/ so I copied extraheader.phtml there and everything working